# Regular expression to replace words from a list by whitespaces

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a list of words **wordsList** and a string **text**.

I need to remove from the **text** words that are in **wordsList**.

Example: "You have knowlegde in Java, PHP, Oracle, etc."

In this case, **you**, **have**, **in** and **etc** are some of the words in wordsList.

So, I need to remove them and replace by a whitespace.

Please, how do I do that?

I think I should visit every item from the list, then check if the text contains it.
What regular expression can I use to replace the words (to remove)?
They can be followed by whitespace or ponctuation.

Expected output for this example:  "knowlegde Java, PHP, Oracle, ."

PS: I can not remove punctuation!
I am using Java.

Comment: Please provide what language you are trying to do this in.

Comment: Portuguese. I already have a file with the words that should be removed. I read the file and created **wordsList**.

Comment: I think hwnd means "what programming language" ... lol +1 for funny.

Comment: This is not a programming service. Tell us what problem you are having making it work.

Comment: My problem is that some words like "initial", after a replace, it becomes "itial" because "in" must be ignored. So I've tried string.replace(" "+wordToRemove+" ", " ") but if wordToRemove is followed by a punctuation char like "etc.", this word is not replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
String text="bla bla ....";
for(String word : wordlist){
   text=text.replaceAll("\\s"+word+"\\s","\\s"); //for detect exactly word in your text.
}
text=text.replaceAll("\\s+","\\s");
```